# How can I make my tabs consistent with CSS?

Tags: css, material-ui

I have implemented an UI. There I have 4 tabs.
The gap between the tabs are different(inconsistent) and If I try to make `width` to `auto`, then the indicator below the tab is not displayed.

code for the tabs -

```
<div class="MuiTabs-flexContainer" role="tablist">
    <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiTab-root jss2 MuiTab-textColorInherit Mui-selected" tabindex="0"   type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="true">
        <span class="MuiTab-wrapper">Aikika</span>
        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
    </button>
    <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiTab-root jss2 MuiTab-textColorInherit" tabindex="-1" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="false">
        <span class="MuiTab-wrapper">Qwertyuio</span>
        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
        </button>
    <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiTab-root jss2 MuiTab-textColorInherit" tabindex="-1" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="false">
        <span class="MuiTab-wrapper">Plmojnuhbtf</span>
        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
        </button>
    <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiTab-root jss2 MuiTab-textColorInherit" tabindex="-1" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="false">
        <span class="MuiTab-wrapper">Tokjl Test</span>
        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

and code for indicator ( underline below to the tab )-

```
<span class="jss3 jss5 MuiTabs-indicator jss1" style="left: 0px; width: 120px;"></span>
```

CSS code is -

```
.MuiTabs-flexContainer button {
    min-width: 120px;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

CSS code for indicator -

```
.jss1 {
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #09728e;
}
```

Currently everything working fine but gap between the tabs are inconsistent. I want my tab to be consistent and indicator should also work fine. I have attached the screenshot for the reference. Red box showing the gap between tab & blue line showing the indicator below the tabs.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this:

```
.MuiTabs-flexContainer{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```